# What is the parameter promotion in variadic functions?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I've heard of parameter promotion in variadic functions, e.g. the `printf` function. When does this occur?

Answer (score 4):

In variadic functions like this:

```
void f(int, ...);
// or
void f(...);
```

the [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) undergo additional conversions known as default argument promotions:

> - `std::nullptr_t` is converted to `void*`
> - `float` arguments are converted to `double` as in floating-point promotion
> - `bool`, `char`, `short`, and unscoped enumerations are converted to `int` or wider integer types as in integer promotion

Note that these conversions do not happen with parameter packs in [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and so are generally preferred over variadic functions.

```
template <typename ...Ts>
void f(Ts ...);             // no promotions here
```

Comment: std::nullptr_t  what is that?

Comment: @FabioDiLieto If you just click on the link that I shared and then click [nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t), you can see that it is the type of the null pointer literal, `nullptr`.